# Place caption within border of image

Tags: html, css, border, caption

[Here is my work so far.](http://codepen.io/league95/full/LGqyLx/)

As you can see I have a white solid border and there is a caption underneath the border. However, I want the caption to be under the picture but within the border, and centered. Here is my code:

```
.img-set {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 700px;
border: 30px solid white;
}
.caption{
align-text: center;
margin: 0 auto;
font-size: 19px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div align="center">
  <img  src="https://upload.wikimedia.
org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Mikhail_Tal_1982.jpg" class="img-set">
  <div class="caption">
    Tal smoking a cigarette
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/okqd4496/) what you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 3):

Fixed your code. The border should be for all the elements within (in this case the image and caption)

--

HTML:

```
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 align="center">Mikhael Tal</h1>
    <h5 align="center">The magician from Riga</h5>
    <figure class="img-set">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Mikhail_Tal_1982.jpg">
        <figcaption align="center">Mikhael Tal smoking a cigarette</figcaption>
     </figure>
  </body>


  </html>
```

--

CSS:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: italic;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 45px;
  font-family: italic;
  font-style: italic;
}

body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.img-set {
  border: 30px solid white;
  width: 700px;

  margin: 0 auto;
}

.img-set img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

figcaption{
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

(spacing added)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add any content to the border, but [here is my solution on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEzrXv) (note that I also made some useful changes to your code so it complies better to the standards).

**The solution explained**

I have removed the border from the image. I then wrapped the image in a `div` element (`img-container`).

I've set the container's background color to white, and set padding of 30 pixels. This way I achieved a visual border of 30 pixels for the image, which is inside that container.

```
.image-container {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

Inside the div, after the image (`img-set`), there is also the caption. Note that I added `margin-bottom: 30px;` to the image, so it looks better.

Comment: I've updated the CodePen URL to the fixed one. Sorry I made a mistake. Please upvote back.

Comment: Hey Ariel, thanks. but why is the figure-caption class empty? and why did you add it to my caption in html? Also, what does inline-block mean? and how is it different than just block?

Comment: Hello @Nisha Shlaymoon. You may add style to figure-caption using CSS, I did not do that because it wasn't essential for the solution :).
About inline-block, read more about it here - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp
Generally, I used it because I wanted the container div's width to be just as wide as the content (which is the image in this case).