# Positioning caption within image border while maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I'm dealing with images that may or may not have a caption.

I've created a polaroid effect around each image via the following:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
<img src="daenerys.png" style="border: 10px solid #FAFAFA;border-bottom: 45px solid #FAFAFA;-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #9E9E9E; -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #9E9E9E;box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #9E9E9E;">
</div>
```

Results look acceptable:

[image]

But this can't support captions the way I want it to. I need to write a caption under the image, within the white border of the polaroid effect.

I changed my code to:

```
<div style="text-align:center;background-color: #ffffff;display: inline-block;padding: 10px;-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #9E9E9E; -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #9E9E9E;box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #9E9E9E;">
<img src="daenerys.png" style="display: block;margin: 0 auto;margin-bottom: 20px;width: 100%;">
<div class="cxl cgy"></div>
</div>
```

This gives me an image that is stretched:

[image]

How do I keep my image resolution and aspect ration intact, while ensuring the text dynamically grows the white space under the image as required? I've taken a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374598/place-caption-within-border-of-image) for help, but to no avail.

The overall goal is to keep the polaroid look (even for images that have no caption), and to use the white space below the image to display text for images that do have captions.

Comment: Why were you trying to turn the image into a block anyway? Just leave the image alone and put the text below it, maybe absolutely positioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution with keeping aspect ration:

```
<div style="text-align:center;background-color: #ffffff;display: inline-block;padding: 10px;-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #9E9E9E;-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #9E9E9E;box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #9E9E9E;">
        <div style="display: inline-table;">
            <img src="daenerys.png" style="display: block;margin: 0 auto;margin-bottom: 20px;width: 100%;">
        <div class="cxl cgy" style="display: table-caption;width: 100%;caption-side: bottom;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae necessitatibus architecto quis non error placeat illo enim illum quo corrupti molestias id sint recusandae animi obcaecati, laudantium nostrum fugit eaque.
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is preview link : https://codepen.io/ziruhel/pen/RjwmQg

Comment: I took a look at your preview link. I actually need the caption to be positioned right below the image, within the polaroid effect.

Comment: I change the image for clear understanding.. 
now you can have another look on  preview link.

if it is not ok, then can you please give me an snapshot of what you want.

Comment: Oh now I see what you're trying to accomplish :-) I'll get back to you in a bit.

Comment: Btw, one more thing. What would I need to do to center align the whole thing within the parent div or page containing it? Should I add `text-align:center` to `<div style="display: inline-table;">`? What would you suggest.

Comment: I think parent div is better, because it will automatically inherited to it's child element.

Comment: If you find my answer correct you may accept my answer. 
It might help others.

Comment: Yes I will, just testing out all the edge cases

Comment: I've accepted the answer, but help me understand one thing. Why did you add `<div style="display: inline-table;">` to the code? If I remove it, it makes no difference at all. Should I keep it?

Comment: `display: inline-table;` take the width that's it's content need and when we used it with `display: table-caption;`., it's take the width of it's parent of table type of display.

Answer (score 0):

For creating how you want to create the polariod, there is a new html tag that can have a caption and and image inside one element.

The Structure is this :

```
-- Figure
---- img
---- figcaption
```

I have made a jsfiddle keeping in mind your structure and the code also.

You can style the figure tag with your card stylings and also keep the text for caption if you want.

The jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/vmt5w1u8/

SCSS code:

```
figure {
text-align: center;
background-color: #ffffff;
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px;
height: 100%;
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #9e9e9e;
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #9e9e9e;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #9e9e9e;

img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
figcaption {
    text-align: center;
}
}
```

Figure tag reference link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting image stretch is because you are not setting a fix/max width for your div, without width specified text will stretch the image as the width gets longer

**Try adding:**

```
div{
    /*width:300px; use max-width if responsive*/
    max-width: 300px; /*maximum width the image will stretch*/
    box-sizing: border-box; /*include padding as part of the specified max-width above*/
}
```

**Example:**

```css
div {
  max-width: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center;background-color: #ffffff;display: inline-block;padding: 10px;-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #9E9E9E; -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #9E9E9E;box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #9E9E9E;">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x250/4168a3/fff" style="display: block;margin: 0 auto;margin-bottom: 20px;width: 100%;">
  <div class="cxl cgy">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
    sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would this work if my images are uploaded by users, and can hence be of variable width? Is it absolutely necessary to take the `max-width` route?

Comment: You can add max width to your universal CSS file or simply add an inline style with max-width to your template, so even when user upload an image the style would automatically be added.

Comment: Actually you're right; I'm going to inline it. The image width is contained in a variable called `wid`, and in Django, these can be injected straight into the HTML template via writing `{{ wid }}`.

Comment: Need one clarification: should I just add `max-width: 300px;` and `box-sizing: border-box;` inline in the outermost div?

Comment: yes or you could just add `max-width: 300px;` to the `img` tag only

Comment: If thats the case, how about you just apply to the div itself? id there is still white space just use a smaller width.

Answer (score 0):

Setting max width to your image might help. Image will be resized to fit the aspect ratio without stretching beyond required width. And also the text content will be wrapped accordingly.

**CSS:**

```
.img-wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MBLZx/2314/).
Hope this helps :)

Comment: The good news is that the image is displayed at the correct aspect ratio thanks to your code. However, the white border around it remains stretched, so the issue remains unresolved. Here's how it looks: https://imgur.com/a/9oEZV

Comment: I have updated the code to solve this problem. Make your image width 100%. Here is the solution http://jsfiddle.net/MBLZx/2314/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set `max-width`, just set `.image` width to `width: 100%` and `height: auto`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MBLZx/2312

Comment: Problem is, this scales up images to 100% of the parent div's width even when they're small.

Comment: @HassanBaig Then I think you have to use Javascript too

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stsxhgwj/1/

Comment: Aahh, was hoping for pure CSS goodness. See, some of my usersoriginate from a forward proxy that strips out JS headers.